# Partially specializing template class in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I've got a template class:

```
template <typename T> struct randimpl {
    // default is to not compile, have to pass T to something to get assert
    // evaluated during second phase expansion, is_void is an arbitrary choice.
    static_assert(
        std::is_void<T>::value && false, "random() not implemented for type"
    );
};
```

This is just a proxy for a `random()` function that can be overloaded for user-defined types:

```
// random function, proxies request through randimpl
template <typename T> T random() {
    return randimpl<T>::random();
}
```

Which I'm trying to partially specialize for a type `_point1d<T>`:

```
// generate random instances _point1d<T>
template <typename T>
struct randimpl<_point1d<T>> {
    static _point1d<T> random() {
        return _point1d<T>(random<T>());
    }
};
```

Which as far as I can tell is the appropriate syntax, but when I compile, I get:

```
inc/geometry.h: In static member function ‘static _point1d<T> randimpl<_point1d<T> >::random()’:
inc/geometry.h:287:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
             return _point1d<T>(random<T>());
                               ^
inc/geometry.h:287:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
             return _point1d<T>(random<T>());
                                        ^
inc/geometry.h:287:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
             return _point1d<T>(random<T>());
```

Is my syntax off?  This seems like it should work, but I don't understand why it's not accepting it.

Comment: `return _point1d<T>(::random<T>());`

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_void<T>::value && false, "")` is technically UB. `always_false<T>::value` is an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `static` member function's name `random` hides the global one, it's trying to invoke itself (i.e. recursive call). But it's not a template and doesn't match how it's called.

You can add [`::` (scope resolution)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers) to specify the global `random`, e.g.

```
// generate random instances _point1d<T>
template <typename T>
struct randimpl<_point1d<T>> {
    static _point1d<T> random() {
        return _point1d<T>(::random<T>());
        //                 ^^
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T51XVERWhEuHpAol)

Comment: An excellent catch, I changd it (see my post), but I'm getting the same exact error messages.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, random wasn't in the global namespace, adding the explicit namespace to it fixes it as expected, thank you!